# When to mean center variables

Tags: regression

I learned recently that you need to mean center variables for regression. I have a few follow up questions:

1. Do you mean center variables before any advanced analysis (e.g. SEM, MLM, LGM) or just regression?
2. Is mean centering required for regression or it okay to **not** mean center variables?
3. Is mean centering only necessary for nominal regression or for continuous predictors as well?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Mean centring is not needed for ordinary linear regression so long as you allow an intercept term

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jenna.  Because it is difficult to answer questions like this that are predicated on an assertion that is not generally true, could you please supply a context and a reference concerning why one might need to center variables for regression?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jenna.  This appears to be about material already well covered on the site.  Please read the duplicate thread and other related threads linked therein.  If you still have a question afterwards, come back here & edit your Q to state what you've learned & what you still need to know.  Then we could best help you.